# Is there a LEFT (Transact-SQL) equivalent in c#?

Tags: t-sql, c#-4.0

Like for example I'm trying to pull the first 3 characters of a prefix from an UserId like TRD2343.

Using (`left('TRD2343', 3)`) in SQL I'm able to do this easily.

In C# is there something easier or I'm stuck using loops?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Takes 3 chars from left

```
var id = "TRD2343";
var prefix = id.Substring(0, 3); // returns TRD
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the substring method in C#

```
 UserId.Substring(0,3)
```

Answer (score 1):

Substring is a pretty standard String utility. You could get `LEFT(myString, 3)` like this:

```
myString.Substring(0,3)
```